# Read Data From SQL using Webservice VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2013

i have a program to read data from sql server using vb .net web service but i have an error when i run my code like this

http://prntscr.com/apmahp

my code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function TopKill() As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_User;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim killing As Integer
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT TOP 20 Name, [Kill], Death FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join(tbl_base) ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC"), con)
    Dim killreader As SqlDataReader
    killreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    killreader.Read()
    If killreader.HasRows Then
        killing = killreader.Item("Name").ToString
        killing = killreader.Item("Kill").ToString
        killing = killreader.Item("Death").ToString
    End If
    con.Close()
    Return killing
End Function ' TOP 20 Killer
```

i don't know how to fix it.
any one can help me to fix my code

thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Mind the spaces, use the edited query below

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT TOP 20 Name, [Kill], Death FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC"), con)
```

This should work because there was a space missing after the `Join`

[image]

Hope this helped

Comment: Please change this (tbl_base) to just tbl_base

Comment: @AndrePabertiyan, can you explain a bit more

Comment: killing = killreader.Item("Name").ToString the data in SQL is varchar ... if i read integer not error my code

Comment: @AndrePabertiyan can you post your error like you did before? To say that you cannot assign a string type to an integer type

Comment: my another post sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498861/webservice-vb-net-read-data-sql-server-2008-r2 please help me

Comment: @AndrePabertiyan I will help with the other but if this helped pls mark as right answer