# webservice vb.net read data sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, web-services, sql-server-2008

i have 2 problem with my program when i wanna read data from sql server. my problem

1. when i wanna read data type varchar from sql server 2008 r2 got error like this http://prntscr.com/apni8g and when i read data type integer from sql no error.

my code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function TopKill() As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim killing As String
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT TOP 20 Name FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC"), con)
    Dim killreader As SqlDataReader
    killreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    killreader.Read()
    If killreader.HasRows Then
        killing = killreader.Item("Name").ToString
    End If
    con.Close()
    Return killing
End Function ' TOP 20 Killer
```

2. when i read 2 data integer why output only one like this http://prntscr.com/apnjnk

my code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function TopKill() As Integer
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim killing As String
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT TOP 20 [Kill], Death FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC"), con)
    Dim killreader As SqlDataReader
    killreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    killreader.Read()
    If killreader.HasRows Then
        killing = killreader.Item("Kill").ToString
        killing = killreader.Item("Death").ToString
    End If
    con.Close()
    Return killing
End Function ' TOP 20 Killer
```

i don't know how to fix it.
i realy need help to fix my code.
maybe anyone can help me to fix my code

thanks before

Comment: in SQL when i run my code like this http://prntscr.com/apo1xa

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to remove the `TOP 20` portion of the SQL to see if that is throwing the `SqlDataReader` off into thinking the first field is an integer column.  If so, then try forcing SQL to interpret the field as a numeric: `SELECT TOP 20 CAST([Kill] AS NVARCHAR(20)), Death FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC`

Comment: my error in number 1 sir trying read varchar data ... for query `SELECT TOP 20 CAST([Kill] AS NVARCHAR(20)), Death FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC` not problem

Comment: I understand that.  The `[Kill]` column is supposed to be returning a string value.  But the error message you show indicates that .Net thinks that this column _should_ be returning an Integer.  When the `SqlDataReader` evaluates a SQL statement it internally attempts to determine what each column in your SELECT statement _should_ return for data, so that later when you request a value, it will be properly casted into the correct data type for you.  So we need determine why does the `SqlDataReader` _think_ that this column is numeric? Is it because of the `TOP 20`, etc.?

Comment: I see that I commented on the wrong SQL, but the same still applies.  It's using a `TOP 20` and the `SqlDataReader` thinks the `Name` column is an integer.

Comment: I must add cast in my query name?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Function

```
Public Function TopKill() As Integer
```

Now look at what you are returning

```
Dim killing As String
....
Return killing
```

Your function is expecting to return an Integer and you are passing a String.. well actually a String array

Change to

```
Public Function TopKill() As String
```

As for your second issue

You are over writing the Kill value with Death... the function gives an answer as it is Cast'able' as an Integer so VB does this for you.

**UPDATE**

Looking at your code you need to output a datatable not a string (array)
So change function to

```
    <WebMethod> _
Public Function Function TopKill() As DataTable

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim SelectQry As String = "SELECT TOP 20 Name FROM tbl_pvporderview  Join tbl_base ON tbl_pvporderview.serial = tbl_base.Serial ORDER BY [Kill] DESC"

    Dim da As New Sqldataadapter()
    Dim Command As New SqlCommand(SelectQry, con)
    da.selectedCommand = Command
    Dim dtresults As DataTable = newDataTable()

    Try
        con.Open()
        da.Fill(dtresults)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    Return dtresults

End Function
```

The returned results will be a datatable with the Top 20 Name, Kill and Death records.

Comment: Actually.... looking closer at your code... you are not returning an array you are returning only one record... either the first of last... your best bet is to read up on returning a json object or a datatable ... you can then return your name, kill and death values.

Comment: where i put this code Dim output as String() = Function TopKill()? and this output.count? i don't know